# Mongoose reference other collection via ObjectID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have read through [this guide](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) for building databases. And I understand it, but I want to implement this idea in my own RESTful API, but it seems I'm going against what's intended with what I have so far come up with.

In the MongoDB documentation linked it talks about saving space by simply referencing the ObjectID, and I was trying to do that and following the Mongoose population docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

But after implementing this I am left with full question data being added to my User, like shown:

[image: image of mongodb document]

Instead of how it's suggested in MongoDB:

```
{
    name : 'left-handed smoke shifter',
    manufacturer : 'Acme Corp',
    catalog_number: 1234,
    parts : [     // array of references to Part documents
        ObjectID('AAAA'),    // reference to the #4 grommet above
        ObjectID('F17C'),    // reference to a different Part
        ObjectID('D2AA'),
        // etc
    ]
```

Due to the potential size of a question, I don't want to embed the questions within a user, but have their ID referenced and then use that to get all *that specific users* questions via their questions array. I did manage to just save an array in mongoose but found I couldn't find how to extract the full documents from the IDs and display them all, so if possible an example of that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use [mongoose-autopopulate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate) plugin

> example

```
   var bandSchema = new Schema({
      name: String,
      lead: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'people', autopopulate: true }
    });
    bandSchema.plugin(autopopulate);

    var Band = mongoose.model('band3', bandSchema, 'bands');
    Band.findOne({ name: "Guns N' Roses" }, function(error, doc) {
      assert.ifError(error);
      assert.equal('Axl Rose', doc.lead.name);
      assert.equal('William Bruce Rose, Jr.', doc.lead.birthName);
      done();
    });
```

or you can try this

```
Modelname.find({})
            .populate('fieldname')           
            .exec(function(error, posts) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(posts, null, "\t"))
            })
```

Comment: I want to stick with just mongoose at the moment, that just confuses me and im not sure if its the solution im after :s

Comment: this is very simple once you try this and it will help you in future